# Twitter Bootstrap timepicker without AM/PM button in View side

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I have this timepicker with bootstrap: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C3b4t/66/)

Now I whant to hide AM/PM, is it possible to do with `javascript`. Or I will have to remove it from `bootstrap.timepicker.js`?

I have try with this:

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker({
    defaultTime: 'value',
    minuteStep: 1,
    disableFocus: true,
    format: 'HH:mm',
    template: 'dropdown'
});
```

But this is not working.

Realy thanks for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add option `showMeridian` as follows,

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker({
    defaultTime: 'value',
    minuteStep: 1,
    disableFocus: true,
    template: 'dropdown',
    showMeridian:false
});
```

This property has default value as `true` which makes the API to operate in 12hr mode. By setting it to `false` turns it to operate in 24hr mode.

Comment: Thanks for the greatest sharing bro

Answer (score 1):

Unforunately, your library doesn't have format option, but you can use 24-hour format:

```
showMeridian: false
```

I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C3b4t/69/

If you want to use 'format' parameter I would suggest you to use `datetimepicker`: [Bootstrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)