# How to remove AM or PM in Time Picker boostrap

Tags: css, timepicker, adminlte

I am using Time Picker of [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/advanced.html) , how can I limit user to pick AM or PM only in time picker. When clicking time picker in AM, PM must not be show

[image]

In Addition here's the code:

**View:**

```
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>FROM</label>
        <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".timepicker").timepicker({
        showInputs: false
    });


});
```

Comment: You can Use `$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'HH:mm'});
` in `Jquery`

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767950/twitter-bootstrap-timepicker-without-am-pm-button-in-view-side

Comment: Sir David I already check that post that code make AM and PM disappeared, In my case I want to remove AM or PM only and not both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so just hide the buttons

```
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table tr:nth-child(3)>td:last-child a {
  display: none;
}

.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table tr:nth-child(1)>td:last-child a {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: i think you need some limitation on the time. there are plenty of JS ways but hiding buttons is the easiest CSS only hack

Comment: wow, its working, can you put the link where can I study that code? thanks a lot sir

Comment: @MathewMagante this is pure css. i have selected the top and bottom arrows of the AM/PM part and made them invisible. thats it.